# How to position a relative element after a fixed element

Tags: html, css

I am stuck in my attempt to get a `position:relative` element to display after a `position:fixed` element. As you can see in my snippet there is a green section and a blue one. The blue section is the fixed element, and the green being the relative element. With `padding-top` I can get the content of this section to start after the fixed element, but then the `padding-top` basically hides the fixed section.

How am I able to place the relative section 100vh from the top of the screen, so it enables the fixed section to be 100vh? Then when scrolling down the relative section starts to show.

```css
#page-wrap {
 margin-top: 70px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
#homeMain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
  background: blue;
}
#sectionCover {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 100vh;
 /*z-index: 1;*/
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <section id="homeMain">
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </section>
  <div id="sectionCover">
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `margin-top` instead of `padding-top` in your relative element.
and also need to give `padding-top: 100vh` to  `#page-wrap` so scroll height adjust.

```css
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#page-wrap {
 margin-top: 70px;
 max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
#homeMain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
  top:0;
  background: blue;
}
#sectionCover {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 100vh;
 /*z-index: 1;*/
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <section id="homeMain">
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </section>
  <div id="sectionCover">
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `padding-top` use `margin-top` and apply some *positioning* to the `fixed` element:

```css
#page-wrap {
  margin-top: 70px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#homeMain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; /* added */
  left: 0; /* added */
  background: blue;
}

#sectionCover {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100vh; /* modified */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <section id="homeMain">
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </section>
  <div id="sectionCover">
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change position to absolute

```
#homeMain {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    **position: absolute;**
    background: blue;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```css
#page-wrap {
 margin-top: 70px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
#homeMain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    z-index:2;
}
#sectionCover {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 100vh;    
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <section id="homeMain">
    <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </section>
  <div id="sectionCover">
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p><p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  <p>fndskjafndoaf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```